# Plot count of specific value across multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

My dataset looks like this:

| V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I want to plot a count of the occurrences of 1s per variable, but on one single bar chart (4 bars). I can plot this for each individual variable using ggplot:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = v1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'count')
```

, but to plot them all on one graph I seem to need to turn my dataframe sideways, but then I can't figure out how to calculate the count of 1s.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the `sum` by column with summarise/across, reshape to long with `pivot_longer` and then use `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), sum)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name)) + 
     geom_col() + 
     coord_flip()
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), V2 = c(0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), V4 = c(1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `barplot` + `stack` + `colSums`

```
barplot(values ~ ind, stack(colSums(df)))
```

or a more concise way (thank @akrun for the comments)

```
barplot(colSums(df))
```

[image]

Comment: I guess `barplot(colSums(df))` would be concise as `barplot` can make use of named vectors (from `colSums`)

Comment: @akrun Yes, really, it works! I learn a new use of barplot, thank you man :)